# Using window opener for a function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I've got a function using an API that redirects me to a callback URL. I then want to execute a function in my base javascript. I'm able to use window.opener to execute the function as long as I keep the function in a separate, non-angular, JS script. However, when I try to execute an angular function I just get an undefined error.

For clarity, here's what **works**:

callbackpage.html:

```
window.opener.inviteCallback();
```

index.html

```
<script>
        function inviteCallback() {
            console.log('Hey Im working')
        };
    </script>
... then onto some angular code
```

And now what **doesn't work**:

callbackpage.html:

```
window.opener.$scope.inviteCallback();
```

controller.js

```
.controller('MainCTRL', function($scope) {
    var inviteCallback = function() {
            console.log('Hey Im working')
        };}
```

I'm using facebook connect using the Requests API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this, add $window as dependency to controller.

```
    myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window){
        $window.inviteCallback = function() {
            alert('hi');
        }           
    });
```

And call inivteCallback using,

```
window.opener.inviteCallback();
```

Comment: If you are using angular in the child page, I recommend using $window.opener instead.

Comment: What happens when the Angular app is destroyed? Is there a memory leak danger?